# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder Async Producer error handling and handle retries

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I am using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder to produce message into Kafka.
 I have kept producer sync to false.
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer.sync: false`

 I faced one issue while producing asynchronously to Kafka, some messages are getting lost if leader (broker) of the partition goes down and there is no any exception logged.

 How to configure the async producer to aply endless retry to not lose  any of the messages untill broker will get stable?